# How does implicit <:< help to find type parameters

Tags: scala, implicit

A couple of questions arise while I'm reading 7.3.2 Capturing type constraints
from Joshua's Scala in Depth. The example excerpted from the book:

```
scala> def peek[C, A](col: C)(implicit ev: C <:< Traversable[A]) = (col.head, col)
peek: [C, A](col: C)(implicit ev: <:<[C,Traversable[A]])(A, C)

scala> peek(List(1, 2, 3))
res9: (Int, List[Int]) = (1,List(1, 2, 3))
```

It seems straightforward that `C` is found to be `List[Int]` by the 1st parameter
list. And how `<:<` enforces type constraint by variance is explained in the book.
But I don't quite see how that helps to find `A`.

My understanding is, from 1st parameter list, scala finds out `C: List[Int]`, 
then it looks for `implicit ev: <:<[List[Int], Traversable[A]]`.
At the moment `A` remains unknown.
It "pulls" two implicits `conforms[List[Int]]` and `conforms[Traversable[A]]` to
match `ev`. In either case to satisfy variance, `List[Int] <: Traversable[A]` has to be satisfied, which leads to the finding that `A` is `Int`.

Does it work as what I'm describing here? Especially on how/when `A` is deduced.

Comment: Yes, it works as you describe.

Comment: @pedrofurla You may want to submit that as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [pedrofurla commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998272/how-does-implicit-help-to-find-type-parameters#comment22815250_15998272), you've got it right—with one little qualification. You say that the compiler "pulls" `conforms[Traversable[A]]`, but there's really no need for any such instance here. To take a simplified example where it's very clear what implicits are in scope:

```
trait Foo[-From, +To]

implicit object intListFoo extends Foo[List[Int], List[Int]]
```

Now there's definitely no `Foo[Traversable[Int], Traversable[Int]]` around, but we *can* write the following:

```
scala> implicitly[Foo[List[Int], Traversable[Int]]]
res0: Foo[List[Int],Traversable[Int]] = intListFoo$@8e760f2
```

More or less exactly the same thing is happening in your example. In that case we would have an instance `Traversable[Int] <:< Traversable[Int]` around if we needed it, but we don't for that specific implicit search.